# Jenkins job stuck after command start

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, cmd

I have a problem in my jenkins job and I isolated into one command. So I created another separate job to try to fix it.

So in this job, called "teste" I only have one single command:

```
start cmd /k call "C:\Program Files\myDir\myBat.bat"
```

This opens a separate cmd window running my bat file, which should keep running "forever".

But the problem is when I do it, my jenkins job keeps stuck into a "exit 0" operation that I have no idea from where it came from.
Thats the console:

```
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on Machine01 in workspace C:\workspace\teste
[teste] $ cmd /c call C:\...dir\jenkins.bat

C:\workspace\teste>start cmd /k call "C:\Program Files\myDir\myBat.bat" 

C:\workspace\teste>exit 0
```

Then it keep stuck at that point.

Example of myBat.bat content:

```
echo hi
pause
```

**There's any way to make this call in another window without waiting for its finish?**

Comment: Try `start "" cmd /k "C:\Program Files\myDir\myBat.bat"`...

Comment: Thanks @aschipfl , but didn't work..stills the same problem

Comment: Actually, let me explain in other words.
I would like to trigger one bat file in a different window (which is already being done), but no matter what happens with this other script, I just would like to be able to finish my current console (job).
So the problem is that the jenkins job stills running forever, and I would like it to finish after triggering this "start cmd /k ...."

Comment: Okay @Compo , I've add a content that you may put into the .bat file to simulate. It behaviors exactly in the same way. As its paused, the new cmd never ends but my main cmd stills not exiting.
If somebody make it works with that script, you save my life.

Comment: @Compo the content of that jenkins.bat is exactly that one line highlighted at the top! This line was printed by jenkins itself, when it puts all my script into a single file into the server and execute it.
My job's script has only one line, which I have already provided!

start cmd /k call "C:\Program Files\myDir\myBat.bat"

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't think you understand the problem.
I have a jenkins job, which is executing one batch script with this single line. It's calling another batch to be opened into a separate window. But my initial console doesn't exit, keeping my job running forever, after calling this separate script.
And I only want to make this console to successfully exit after calling the other script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem changing the way I was calling my other .bat, calling it through powershell. But since I was from a bat file, I used the command to send a powershell command, calling my other bat file.
Also, I've added another line changing the jenkins BUILD_ID to a fake one, so it doesn't kill it.

So I changed from this line:

```
start cmd /k call "C:\Program Files\myDir\myBat.bat"
```

To this :

```
set BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
powershell -Command "Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\myDir\myBat.bat'"
```

I hope it helps someone someday.